# backbone pushState root

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

In backbone how do get access to the root of pushState the reason is I want to create a backbone back button but I want to access the root url

`Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root: 'admin/brands/' });`

I want to access root so I can destroy Models and Views using back button so I want to get the brands section part

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like `Backbone.history.root`